# JQuery Hover Code: Adding an If Statement breaks it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, if-statement

I have this code that makes a box with information follow the mouse. It's really simple, just checks the custom attribute "description" in the div that you hover over and puts that in the box. However, I want to make it so if that div also has a certain CSS class, then it would put other information in the box, in addition to the other code still working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hover").mousemove(function(e){
    if ("div").hasclass("item"){
        alert("div hasclass item");
    } else {
        var description = $(this).attr("description");
        $("#hoverdiv").text(description).show();
        $("#hoverdiv").css("top", e.clientY+10).css("left", e.clientX+5);
    }

}).mouseout(function(){
    $("#hoverdiv").hide();
});
```

});

that's the code I have now. None of the hovers in my page work at all. This is the code that works. It's identical in every way, except no if statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hover").mousemove(function(e){
    var description = $(this).attr("description");
    $("#hoverdiv").text(description).show();
    $("#hoverdiv").css("top", e.clientY+10).css("left", e.clientX+5);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $("#hoverdiv").hide();
});
```

});

I've tried time and time again to get this to work, and through my testing, it would seem that simply adding an if statement breaks the entire thing. I have absolutely no idea how to proceed or how to fix it.

Comment: Your if condition is badly formatted.

Comment: Why is the if statement even useful? `$("div").hasClass` doesn't make any sense

Comment: The "correct" answer here is "figure out how to use your JS debugger".  For example in Chrome, the JavaScript console will output an error pointing exactly to the code line at fault.

Answer (score 3):

The culrpit..

```
 if ("div")
```

Maybe you were trying

```
if($("div").something()){
}
```

Comment: Next time check your `console` or `firebug` messages. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ("div").hasclass("item") {
```

Should be:

```
if ( $("div").hasClass("item") ) {
```

For some more you can also test:

```
if ( $("div").is(".item") ) {
```

Read about jQuery **[*`.is()`*](http://api.jquery.com/is)**